# Issue with installing Bazel for TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build TensorFlow from source but run into an issue. Once I have everything installed and need to configure TensorFlow, I run the command "python ./configure.py" in VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt but it says that it cannot find Bazel and that I need to install it. The problem is that I did download it, changed the binary to bazel.exe and changed the %PATH% for it to C:\bazel which is where I put it. I also added the other requirements for %PATH% in my environment variables. Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Did you set the `BAZEL_SH` to the path of the MSYS2 Bash (e.g. `c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe`)? Did you follow these installation instructions: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.25.0/install-windows.html

Comment: Yeah I actually just figured it out.

Comment: Did this solve your issue?